# WordPress Slider Widget Repositions Web Page

Tags: wordpress, image, widget, slider

As soon as smart slider 3 (image slider) starts loading, I run into the following issue: no matter where I am on the web page, the web page repositions to the section where the slider is located. This occurs only when the slider is activated. Otherwise, I do not experience this problem.

The slider is set up to load only when it is 100% viewed and stops upon mouse hovering.

I've messed with the settings in smart slider 3 and it seems like there aren't any fixes in the basic version. I've also read that there are codes for manually built sliders that can fix this.

I am hoping if there was a work around for this widget instead of coding a new slider from scratch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slider settings -> General -> Scroll to slider and disable autoplay

https://s3.amazonaws.com/helpscout.net/docs/assets/5620be92c69791452ed4c442/images/5cac30df0428633d2cf4985f/file-UlaVVGbbpO.png